# Find string in text, remove the first and last char

Tags: c#, regex, string

I search in a text for some strings and want to remove the first and last char in those strings.

Example :

```
...
...
OK 125 ab_D9 "can be "this" or; can not be "this" ";
...
OK 673 e_IO1_ "hello; is strong
or maybe not strong";
...
```

So I use the code to find all strings begin with OK and remove from the 4 groups "...":

```
tmp = fin.ReadToEnd();
var matches = Regex.Matches(tmp, "(OK) ([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z_0-9]+) (\"(?:(?!\";).)*\");", RegexOptions.Singleline);
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
         matches[i].Groups[4].Value.Remove(0);

         matches[i].Groups[4].Value.Remove(matches[i].Groups[4].Value.ToString().Length - 1);
         Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Groups[1].Value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + matches[i].Groups[2].Value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + matches[i].Groups[3].Value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + matches[i].Groups[4].Value);
         Console.WriteLine("           ");
    }
```

But it doesn't remove first and last char from Group 4. What did I do wrong?

My Result should be:

```
 OK

 125

 ab_D9


 can be "this" or; can not be "this" 


 OK

 673

 e_IO1

 hello; is strong
 or maybe not strong
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want to strip all outer quotes in the last part of the line?

Comment: yes, i just want to remove `"`from the group 4, but just from the beginning and the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to remove things. Just don't capture the quotes in the first place. So move the parentheses one character inward.

```
"(OK) ([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z_0-9]+) \"((?:(?!\";).)*)\";"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the result of `Substring()` and `Remove()` methods. they do not change the existing string but return the changed string which you need to assign to the same or some other string variable. Check the code:

```
tmp = fin.ReadToEnd();
var matches = Regex.Matches(tmp, "(OK) ([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z_0-9]+) (\"(?:(?!\";).)*\");", RegexOptions.Singleline);
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
         string str = matches[i].Groups[4].Value.Substring(0);

         str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
         Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Groups[1].Value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + matches[i].Groups[2].Value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + matches[i].Groups[3].Value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + str);
         Console.WriteLine("           ");
    }
```

P.S. You should use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\r\n"`, it's the better approach.